# Terence Tao, Analysis 1. Exercise 5.3.2. Real Numbers and Cauchy Sequences.

Tags: analysis

Let $ x = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n, y = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n$, and $ x' = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a'_n$ be real numbers. Then $xy$ is also a real number. Furthermore, is $x=x'$, then $xy = x'y$.

Here is my attempt.

We need to show that $xy = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n b_n$ is a real number.

from the hypothesis we know that $a_n$ and $b_n$. are eventually $\delta$ -steady sequences for every $\delta> 0 $. so we can choose $a_n$ and $b_n$ to be eventually $\sqrt{\epsilon}$-steady sequences.

since $(a_n)_{n=1}$ is eventually $\sqrt{\epsilon}$-steady, we know there is an $N \geq 1$ such that $d(a_n,a_m) < \sqrt{\epsilon}$  for every $n,m > N$. By a similar argument we can say the same for $(b_n)_{n=1}$.

by proposition 4.3.7 (h).

$d(a_nb_n,a_mb_m) < \sqrt{\epsilon}|b_n| + \sqrt{\epsilon}|a_n| + \epsilon $

From here i am not sure where to go, I am pretty sure i am going the right way, as this sort of resembles the definition of a cauchy sequence that is eventually $\sqrt{\epsilon}|b_n| + \sqrt{\epsilon}|a_n| + \epsilon $-close. I think I require something that just involves epsilon.

The second part of the question I havent attempted yet, but I thought I'd include it just in case anyone would like to lend a helping hand.

by the way propostion 4.3.7 (h). states that if x and y are $\epsilon$-close and z and w and $\delta$ close then xz and yw are $(\epsilon|z| + \delta|x| + \epsilon \delta$)-close.

EDIT.

A real number is defined to be an object of the form $ x = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n$, where $a_n$ is a cauchy sequence of rational numbers.

Comment: The capital LIM as oppose to lim is used as a crutch to introduce limits, sorry for not accepting edits.

Comment: Then you'll need to give a context for what LIM means.

Comment: If you're using this definition, then actually a real number is an equivalence class of Cauchy sequences of rational numbers.

Comment: Thanks, would any of you guys happen to know where i have messed up?

Comment: $ \lim n \rightarrow \infinity a_n b_n  $

Comment: is how its defined in  the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

${\bf 1.}$ Let $a.$ and $b.$ be two Cauchy sequences of rational numbers. Then
$$a_mb_m-a_nb_n=a_m(b_m-b_n)+b_n(a_m-a_n)$$
and therefore
$$|a_mb_m-a_nb_n|\leq |a_m|\>|b_m-b_n|+|b_m|\>|a_m-a_n|\ .\tag{1}$$

Since Cauchy sequences are bounded there is a common bound $C>0$ for the $|a_n|$ and the $|b_n|$. Let an $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then there is an $N\in{\mathbb N}$ such that the two sequences are ${\epsilon\over 2C}$-steady for $n\geq N$. On account of $(1)$ this implies that

$$|a_mb_m-a_nb_n|\leq C{\epsilon\over 2C}+C{\epsilon\over2C}=\epsilon\qquad(m, \>n\geq N)\ ,$$
which proves that the sequence $c_n:=a_nb_n$ $\>(n\geq1)$ is Cauchy, whence defines a real number.

${\bf 2.}$ A similar argument, using the inequality
$$|a_n'b_n-a_n b_n|\leq C\>|a_n'-a_n|\ ,$$
proves that $x'y\sim xy$ when $x'\sim x$.

Comment: Why is every answer being downvoted?

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer, i never organised a bounty before, i think i have just awarded it to you.... so yeah, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

**Multiplication of Cauchy Sequences**

Real numbers are being defined as Cauchy sequences rational numbers.  We can multiply two sequences of numbers to get another sequence.  Will it also be Cauchy?

> **Lemma**: If $a_n$ and $b_n$ are Cauchy, then $a_n b_n$ is also Cauchy

In the case of the real numbers, Cauchy sequences are not just close, they are guaranteed to have a limit. I don't quite remember how the proof goes.

> **Lemma**: If $a_n$ and $b_n$ are Cauchy with limits $x$ and $y$, then $a_n b_n$ is Cauchy with limit $xy$

Finally there is a question of whether two *different* sequences can represent the same number?  What about:

$$  1- \frac{1}{n} \hspace{0.25in}\text{ vs }\hspace{0.25in} 1 + \frac{1}{n} $$

In your case you just want to *subtract* the Cauchy sequences, and get $$xy - x'y = (x - x')y = 0\cdot y = 0$$

However $\mathbf{0}$ here means "**a Cauchy sequence converging to $0 \in \mathbb{Q}$**".  So all the steps here need to be checked carefully.  Can you do that?

---

**Comment** In real life sequences are definitely *not* Cauchy, e.g. $(-1)^n$.  Or in reality $(-1)^{f(n)}$ where $f(n)$ is something totally random and may chance over time.

---

Think about it for a little bit, for very large $n > M$, then $a_M - \epsilon < a_n < a_M + \epsilon$ and a similar statement for $b_n$.  Then:

$$
(a_m - \epsilon)(b_m - \delta) < a_n b_n < (a_m + \epsilon)(b_m + \delta)  $$

The error term is like $(\epsilon b_m + \delta a_m) + \delta \epsilon$ which is Tao's proposition.  How big is this error?

$$ (\epsilon (b_N + \delta) + \delta (a_M + \epsilon)) + \delta \epsilon
= (\delta a_M  + \epsilon b_N) + 3\delta \epsilon$$

This is getting rather expensive I suspect $\epsilon^\ast = \delta a_M  + \epsilon b_N$.

---

Summary: **to multiply two Cauchy sequences $a_nb_n$ and get to be $\epsilon$-close to $xy$, we must truncate much further than to get $a_n$ to be $\epsilon$-close to $x$ or 
$b_n$ to be $\epsilon$-close to $y$.**

Answer (score -1):

**Proof Part 1 - Cauchy Sequences are Bounded**

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence of rationals.  Let $\epsilon>0$.  Observe there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n,m>N, |a_n - a_m| < \epsilon$.  Consider the ball $B_\epsilon(a_n)$ which contains $a_m$ for all $m>N$.  Therefore consider the points $\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_N\}$.  These points possibly lie outside $B_\epsilon(a_n)$.  Consider now the set of distances $\{\epsilon, d(a_n,a_1), d(a_n,a_2), \ldots, d(a_n,a_N)\}$ and let $M$ be the maximum element of this set.  Then $B_{M+1}(a_n)$ certainly contains all points of the sequence, hence the sequence is bounded.

**Proof Part 2 - Product of Cauchy sequences is Cauchy**

Let $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ be Cauchy sequences of rationals.  By the proof of part 1, we know that each sequence is bounded, therefore let $A = \sup_n \{|a_n|\}$ and $B = \sup_n\{|b_n|\}$.  If both $A = B = 0$ then define $A' = B' = 1$, otherwise let $A' = A$ and $B' = B$.   We want to check that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exist $N \in \mathbb{N}$ where if $m,n > N$ then $|a_nb_n - a_mb_m| < \epsilon$.  There exists $N_1, N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ where if $n,m > N_1$ then $|a_n - a_m| < \frac{\epsilon}{A'+B'}$ and $m,n > N_2$ yields $|b_n - b_m| < \frac{\epsilon}{A'+B'}$.  Let $N = \max\{N_1, N_2\}$.  For $n,m > N$ we have

\begin{eqnarray*}
|a_nb_n - a_mb_m| & = & |a_nb_n - a_nb_m + a_n b_m - b_nb_m| \\
& \leq & |a_nb_n - a_nb_m| + |a_nb_m - a_mb_m| \\
& \leq & |a_n|\cdot |b_n - b_m| + |b_m|\cdot|a_n - a_m| \\
& < & A' \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{A'+B'} + B \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{A'+B'} \;\; =\;\; \epsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}

**Proof Part 3 - $a_nb_n \to xy$**

The argument is similar to part 2.  Let $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ be Cauchy sequences of rationals such that $a_n \to x$ and $b_n \to y$.  Then $\{a_nb_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence of rationals.  Let $\epsilon >0$.  Let $N_1, N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $n>N_1$ then $|a_n - x| < \frac{\epsilon}{A'+|y|}$ and $n>N_2$ yields $|b_n - y| < \frac{\epsilon}{A'+|y|}$, where $A = \sup_n \{a_n\}$ and $A'$ as defined in part 2.  Let $N = \max\{N_1, N_2\}$ and $N>N$. We then find

\begin{eqnarray*}
|a_nb_n - xy| & = & |a_nb_n - a_ny + a_ny - xy| \\
& \leq & |a_nb_n - a_ny| + |a_ny - xy| \\
& \leq & |a_n|\cdot |b_n - y| + |y|\cdot |a_n - x| \\
& < & A'\cdot \frac{\epsilon}{A' + |y|} + |y|\cdot \frac{\epsilon}{A'+|y|} \;\; =\;\; \epsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}

**Proof Part 4**

Let $\{a_n\}, \{b_n\}, \{a_n'\}$ be rational Cauchy sequences where $a_n \to x, \; b_n \to y,$ and $a_n' \to x'$.  Suppose $x = x'$ and consider

\begin{eqnarray*}
xy - x'y & = & \lim_{n\to \infty} a_nb_n - \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n' b_n \\
& = & \lim_{n\to\infty} a_nb_n - a_n'b_n \\
& = & \lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n - a_n')b_n \\
& = & (\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n - \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n')\cdot \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n \\
& = & (x-x')y \;\; =\;\; 0.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Does someone want to explain to me why this was down voted?

Comment: Your answer is impressive. I upvote you. :)

Comment: Thanks Guillaume!  It's much appreciated.  I do however would like to know people's reasons for down voting.  It would be petty if it were merely about the bounty...